# Node JS Upload Image with form

Tags: node.js

Hello I have problem while uploading image using file system module in nodeJS it is problem for large file like 2MB files while uploading

```
fs.readFile(tmpPath,function(err,data){
    fs.writeFile(targetPath, data, function (err) {

    });
});
```

Comment: where is your code for upload file

Comment: What's the problem? Add some code snippet or error log for analysis.

Comment: "it is a problem for large file like 2MB files while uploading". I didn't understand if small files work fine and if 2MB is considered a large size file. Can you clear that in the question?

Comment: i am using it while create api for one form at that time whenever i am attach documents it's unable to give any kind of response i have also used multiparty form module in short need a solution for upload image and other fields with form-data in nodejs